# Problems with amazon SSH but not other SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

why is SSH not working?

I keep getting..

`ssh: connect to host ec2-11-11-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out`

when trying to connect to my amazon EC2 server, at first i thought it was some sort of firewall but i have no firewall and i can SSH in to my MediaTemple server.

the chmod of my pem is 600. and this is how im trying to ssh..

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/ServerKey.pem ubuntu@ec2-11-11-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

i have a AMI ID: ami-508c7839 so i seen on a video the user should be ubuntu.

i hope someone can see an error somewhere because i dont have a clue. if it helps to know im on a mac.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your ssh command in verbose mode to see where exactly it's timing out in.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ServerKey.pem -v ubuntu@ec2-11-11-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Also, I would advice you to specify the absolute path to your ssh key instead of using the ~ tilde sign. (It will save you a headache if you want to auto connect to your EC2 server from a script/cron).

-Tony

Comment: ok, thanks... this is what i got back 

`MacBook-Pro:~ aaranmcguire$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/ServerKey.pem -v ubuntu@ec2-11-11-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-11-11-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com [50.19.33.24] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.19.33.24 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-11-11-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: It sounds like its a firewall issue. You may need to check your Inbound firewall policies on the security group that our instance is using. Make sure the policy "Port 22 (SSH) source 0.0.0.0/0" is set.

Comment: did that and restarted the instance... still the same

Answer (score 2):

Go to Security Group, and make sure the policy "Port 22 (SSH) source 0.0.0.0/0" is set.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have hit "Apply Rule Changes" in Security Groups tab.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is an problem of ssh.
I suggest you check the network reahcability.

Try to ssh the ip address directly.
Try to debug the dns.